# I can't seem to update the value of an object's field in an array in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This seems so damned simple, but I just can't seem to update the value of the pos field in the WorkSetTemplate object in an array.

Here's the code:

```
export class WorkSetTemplate {

  static alignPositionWithDisplay(coll: WorkSetTemplate[]): WorkSetTemplate[] {
    for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].pos = i + 1;
    }
    return coll;
  }

  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public nk?: string,
    public pos?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public maintainerId?: number,
    public airworthinessDirectiveIssueNumber?: string,
    public workItemTemplates?: WorkItemTemplate[]
  ) {}

}
```

lets say I start with the sets:

[image]

I call the static method with:

sets = WorkSetTemplate.alignPositionWithDisplay(sets);

I would expect to see the same arrangement of objects but with the pos values reading in sequence as 1, 2, 3 (not 2, 1, 3)

But no change actually results (i.e., they remain as 2, 1, 3, even though if i console.log inside the for loop the change actually happens (in the loop). So its like the changes are dereferenced when you exit the loop. I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here. Could someone tell me what I've misunderstood?

Comment: @somethinghere  I think that's what he wants to do, he's not wanting to sort, but update `pos` with the `index` value of the array + 1.   What he's saying is that `pos` doesn't update.

Comment: I'm not able to see anything wrong here, you able to produce a simple reproducible snippet.?   Also might be handy to show the code were you calling it too.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I am also a bit mystified. It'll be hard to do a snippet because I think there might be something happening in the background. The WorkSetTemplate values are pulled from an Angular 7 reactive form, so I wonder if there's some two-way binding magic going on. I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

There is something missing from the scenario here, as the items probably change (with or without the return value assignment).

```
interface WorkItemTemplate {
    name: string;
}

class WorkSetTemplate {

  static alignPositionWithDisplay(coll: WorkSetTemplate[]): WorkSetTemplate[] {
    for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].pos = i + 1;
    }
    return coll;
  }

  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public nk?: string,
    public pos?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public maintainerId?: number,
    public airworthinessDirectiveIssueNumber?: string,
    public workItemTemplates?: WorkItemTemplate[]
  ) {}

}

let items = [
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'ABC3', 1),
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'XYZ1', 1),
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'ABC1', 1),
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));

// [
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "ABC3", "pos": 1 },
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "XYZ1", "pos": 1 },
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "ABC1", "pos": 1 }
// ]

// Side note - the objects are changed regardless of assignment
WorkSetTemplate.alignPositionWithDisplay(items);

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));

// [
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "ABC3", "pos": 1 },
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "XYZ1", "pos": 2 },
//   { "id": 5, "nk": "ABC1", "pos": 3 }
// ]
```

Demostration using the transpiled code:

```js
var WorkSetTemplate = /** @class */ (function () {
    function WorkSetTemplate(id, nk, pos, name, maintainerId, airworthinessDirectiveIssueNumber, workItemTemplates) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nk = nk;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.name = name;
        this.maintainerId = maintainerId;
        this.airworthinessDirectiveIssueNumber = airworthinessDirectiveIssueNumber;
        this.workItemTemplates = workItemTemplates;
    }
    WorkSetTemplate.alignPositionWithDisplay = function (coll) {
        for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
            coll[i].pos = i + 1;
        }
        return coll;
    };
    return WorkSetTemplate;
}());
var items = [
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'ABC3', 1),
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'XYZ1', 1),
    new WorkSetTemplate(5, 'ABC1', 1),
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
WorkSetTemplate.alignPositionWithDisplay(items);
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```